# Printar lista dentro de otra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Un profesor toma medidas de las alturas de sus alumnos de su clase.
>   Para cada uno de los 10 alumnos, toma las medidas dos veces al año.
>   Haremos un programa que nos permita introducir 10 valores de altura
>   (Para la primera medida), y 10 valores para la segunda medida. el
>   programa nos mostrará un listado del crecimiento experimentado para
>   cada alumno.

Yo tengo hecho esto:

```
altura=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

i=0

print(altura[i][i])
while i <= 10:
    primera_altura=float(input("Introduce altura: "))
    altura[i][i]=primera_altura
    i=i+1
```

Obviamente no funciona, lo que estoy intentando hacer es crear una lista que tenga 10 sublistas para cada alumno, y después pedir una altura al usuario y añadirlo en el campo i de la lista, así que cada vez que introduzca una altura la introducirá en otra sublista. El problema es que me da un mensaje de error diciendo que se sale del indice de la lista.

Cómo lo podría hacer ?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un ciclo for, que haga una iteración sobre cada elemento de la lista, te pregunte por el valor (altura) que quieres asignar a la lista y lo añada a la lista, tal que así:

```
lista=[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

var_filas=10
var_columnas=2

for row in range(var_filas):
    for col in range(var_columnas):
        altura=input("Introduce altura: ")

        lista[row][col]=altura

print(lista)
```

Como ves, todos los valores de la lista empiezan en 0, y lo que hacemos es sustituirlos por el numero que queramos.

```
var_filas=10
```

Es el número de filas de la lista y

```
var_columnas=2
```

Es el número de columnas de la lista, que es lo mismo que decir que hay 10 elementos que contienen 2 valores cada uno.

Si solo quieres que se puedan añadir números decimales a la lista modifica el input, indicándole que solo se puedan añadir flotantes

```
altura=float(input("Introduce altura: "))
```

Espero haberte sido de ayuda, un saludo, suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba, muy buena explicación, me ha sido muy útil. Saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos problemas:

- **`while i <= 10`:** itera desde 0 hasta 10, lo cual ocasiona un error de indexado ya que los índices en Python son base 0, por lo que en una lista de 10 elementos los índices van desde 0 hasta 9, 10 no es un índice válido.
- **`altura[i][i]`:** tus sublistas están vacías, por lo que no puedes indexar sobre ellas. Solo puedes indexar si la lista contiene un elemento en esa posición previamente.  Por ejemplo, para `lista = [[]]`,  `lista[0]` es válido, pero `lista[0][0]` no dado que la lista anidada no tiene elementos. Para `lista = [[1]]`, `lista[0][0]` es válido y retorna `1`, pero `lista[0][1]` no es un índice válido.

  Por otro lado, debería ser en todo caso `altura[i][0]` para la primera medida y `altura[i][1]` para la segunda medida.

O inicializas tus listas anidadas con valores iniciales, p.e:

```
altura = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

o usas `list.append` para añadir elementos de forma dinámica a la lista.

En vez de un ciclo `while` es más eficiente y "pytónico" usar un `for`:

```
altura=[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

for lista in altura:
    primera_altura = float(input("Introduce altura: "))
    lista.append(primera_altura)
```

> Siempre usa un `for in` para iterar sobre un iterable en vez de indexado **a no ser que modifiques la longitud del iterable mientras iteras sobre él**. En este caso el `for` itera sobre `altura` (la cual no es modificada, solo las listas que contienen lo son).
>
> Es preferible generalmente un `for` frente a un `while` siempre que sea posible. Mejor usar `for i in range(10):` que un `while` como usas tú. Reserva el `while` para cuando el número de iteraciones no esté definido de antemano.